# HighCharts how to make drilldown label show on mobile view?

Tags: css, vue.js, highcharts

On mobile view, the drilldown data label gets the ellipses on my pie chart as shown above, Ideally I would like to move the data label up and remove the dots on the bottom of the word and have the entire word show. Just any styles to make the entire word show would be nice, the word is "streaming"

The styles I have currently are

```
drilldown: {
            activeDataLabelStyle: {
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: '14px',
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `textOverflow` style to `clip`. If you need to manipulate individual data label's position, use `y` or `x` property. Example:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        dataLabels: {
            ...,
            style: {
                textOverflow: 'clip'
            }
        },
        data: [..., {
            ...,
            dataLabels: {
                y: -20
            }
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9Lhokg4t/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels